# Adding to the address of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, operating-system, array-address

This is probably a very discussed question, but I still fail to understand the mechanics:

How do I add 512 to the address of an array?

Here's the situation:

```
char buffer[512];
readSector(buffer,2);

/*somewhere in here i must increment address of buffer by 512*/

readSector(buffer,3);
printString(buffer);
```

readSector takes in the buffer array, and dumps the contents of sector 2 of the disk in it. 
Then readSector is called again in order to have the contents of sector 3 dropped in buffer. printString just prints the contents of the buffer to the screen.

My professor explains that every time I call readSector I should increment the address of
buffer by 512. How do i go about doing this? Again, sorry if this is a blatantly obvious
question or if it has been asked before. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what your Professor really wants; or else he's a really lousy professor.

Comment: You could make a large buffer, like char buffer[2048], then increment via an offset:   readSector((buffer+512),3);

Comment: I got it! After re-reading the prompt, and after consulting the answers here, turns out the offset is what worked. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have anyways asked the question, you should accept the most relevant answer, this way you can close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increment an array. However, you can create a pointer to the first element in the array, and then increment the pointer:

```
char *ptr = &buffer[0];  // Or just char *ptr = buffer;

ptr += 512;
```

However, as pointed out below, your array is **only 512 bytes**.  If you increment by 512, you are now looking past the end of the array, which will subsequently invoke **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: but `buffer` is an array with 512 bytes. Any (de-)reference past that invokes UB.

Comment: The buffer needs to be larger, like several multiples of 512.  I don't think he understands what the Professor is asking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not try to access the array out of bounds, that is accessing memory region after the last address of array. Doing this is an **undefined behavior**

i.e. in `char buffer[512];` you can only access from `*buffer` till `*(buffer +511)`.

To read large data in multiples of `512` you can read the first data set in `buffer`, print it and then overwrite your `buffer` with next data set if old data set is not needed. Otherwise you can pre-allocate `buffer` to be of large size (some multiple of `512` e.g. `1024`, etc.), then simply access the buffer as `buffer` for first data set then `buffer + 512` for next data set, `buffer + 512*2` for third one, and so on.

As others have also pointed out, array name always points to array's base address, you cannot change it, therefore you need to use a dummy pointer say `ptr` to access any index in array.

`char buf[1024];`
`char *ptr = buf;`

`readSector(ptr,2);  // readSector(buf,2);`

`//buf = buf + 512;   // Wrong, compile error`
`ptr = ptr + 512;    // Correct!!`

`readSector(ptr,3);`
`printString(buffer);`

Answer (score 1):

If you increment the `buffer` by `512` -> you will be accessing the array out of the bounds
Try using a matrix:

```
...
char buffer[2][512]; 
readSector(buffer[0],2);
readSector(buffer[1],3);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this question was wrong in its nature. After carefully reading the following instructions:

```
1. Load the directory sector into a 512 byte character array using readSector
2. Go through the directory trying to match the file name.  If you do not find it, return.
3. Using the sector numbers in the directory, load the file, sector by sector, 
into the buffer array.
You should add 512 to the buffer address every time you call readSector
4. Return
```

The buffer array is actually a char array initialized in main() which is set to

```
char buffer[13312];
```

meaning that by just offsetting I can achieve what I want. Thanks nonetheless everyone!.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right, only thing is when you declare

```
 char buffer[512];
```

buffer becomes a const type, tat you can not increment any more.

```
char * p = buffer;
```

Now this p is the same as buffer, but it is not const type, so you can increment p.

```
p += 3;
```

will point to buffer plus 3 location.